# Jquery, get time difference in minutes

Tags: jquery, mysql, datetime

I have a web page with a list of records from a database. For each record there is a timestamp, what I want to do is using the timestamp in mysql I would like to get the time difference in minutes from that timestamp up to the current time. How could I do this via jquery so I can update it in real time instead of having to hit the database over and over again to calculate the time difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many jQuery plug-ins which provide this functionality.  http://timeago.yarp.com/ is the one I'm the most familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The yarp.com script, do you know using something like this will cause any issues with regards to how many rows there are? I dont see there being more than a couple of hundred rows at once at any given time. But do you think this could cause any issues using jquery?

Comment: the timeago plugin is pretty mature.  i imagine you'd be pretty safe but, as always, you should test to make sure the tool will adequately solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need datajs, data/time library (http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) to calculate time span. Other than that, remaining work would be time mapping between mysql and javascript - maybe you can use epoch.

Comment: You can **surely** use epoch, like in the following query: `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_date) FROM my_table;`.